# is it wrong to use full links inside includes?

Tags: php

I've read so many different inputs on this, so I figured I would ask on here.

Is there anything wrong or dangerous about using full links inside a php include?

Examples,

```
<?php include('http://www.domain.com/blah.php'); ?>


<?php
define('WEB_ROOT', './');  // relative path to /
include('layout.php');
?>
```

compared to using

```
<?php
include('../blah.php');
?>
```

Comment: If you are in the same project and including file of that same project they why will you use full url?

Comment: we need to use docroot path for file include not webroot path

Comment: I prefer `include(dirname(__FILE__)."/layout.php");`

Comment: I was just curious mainly about the differences between full url and the others...I received my answer on that.  What is the difference between webroot and docroot paths?  And how exactly does include(dirname(__FILE__)."/layout.php"); work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include('http://www.domain.com/blah.php')` goes out and makes an actual HTTP request to the web server, returning the contents of the URL after the web server has processed them, just as you'd see when entering that URL in your browser.

`include('../blah.php')` includes the local file from disk one directory higher.

The two are completely different things and you do ***not*** want to include a URL when you mean to include a local file. Even if the two are supposedly the same file, PHP cannot know that. Accessing a URL and accessing a local file path are entirely different things. It's not possible to infer that the two are the same.

Comment: I appreciate your detail as it now makes sense between the two.  I was always kind of curious what the difference really was.  Now, to verify  between your answer and the other answer saying full url is dangerous...is define('WEB_ROOT', './'); include('./layout.php'); just as dangerous as full url or is it still pulling local file?  I will be using multiple directories and the user can actually create directories, which is why I'd like to use some sort of path that is universal throughout the entire site instead of using ../../ to go back directories.

Comment: As long as the path does not start with `http://` or some other *protocol*, it's always a local path. So defining a constant is fine, but you should define an *absolute* path like `define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)`. The way better alternative is to use class based programming and autoloading. This is much better for keeping code organized and frees you from thinking about include paths completely.

Comment: Do you have a link of an example of the kind of class you are referring to with autoloading?  Never done this before.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php include('http://www.domain.com/blah.php'); ?>` is very dangerous, you can't know in 100% what is the code you will get!!! becuse PHP do HTTP request and someome can do ManInTheMiddel attack and to change the code you will get, and to hack your site.

Comment: so full url is bad...but something like define('WEB_ROOT', './'); include('./layout.php'); would work and isn't dangerous in that way correct?